# Highlight Normal only for filetype in vim

Tags: vim, highlight, file-type

So, I'm pretty happy that I've discovered how to set highlighting when I open a particular file in vim. I'm doing this for JavaScript files, so most of them are 'hi jsStringD' and 'hi jsFunction' etc.
I use this to trigger it:

```
if has("autocmd")
  augroup JavaScript
    au!
    au BufReadPost *.js call SetUpJavaScript()
  augroup END
...
```

I also want to change the color of 'Normal' or foreground text, but only for JavaScript files.

This works to set the color:

```
execute 'hi Normal ctermfg=' normalText
```

But how do I limit it only to a certain filetype? This results in all files having 'Normal' highlighted to that color.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I open a JavaScript file and it works. I open another file (say a .jade file) and 'Normal' color remains the 'normalText' value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an autocmd that only fires for the javascript file type

```
autocmd FileType javascript execute 'hi Normal ctermfg=' normalText
```

However I think this will have problems if you switch between multiple files in one session since highlighting is global.

To work around this you could add another FileType autocmd that fires on BufEnter (or something like that) that sets a default Normal highlighting.

---

Something like this would work (Although it will change the highlighting in splits when you change focus)

```
autocmd BufEnter * if (&filetype ==# 'javascript') | execute 'hi Search ctermfg=' . normalText | else | execute 'hi Search ctermfg=' . defualtText | endif
```

Comment: Yeah that's the problem. Switching after a .JS file to something else. BufEnter sounds like it would cover some cases, but I'd really like to know how to cover all or nearly all of them...

Comment: Also, I don't know how to say "files that are not .js" when it comes to filegroup :)